# How to remove the line break for a nested enumerate with a marginpar?

Tags: enumerate, marginpar

The MWE below demonstrates my problem.

[image]
I suppose that somehow the marginpar is introducing something on the line and Latex is then treating the line as non empty.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mtext}{\makebox[0pt]{}\marginpar{(hello)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \mtext%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a line too low, at least the marginpar is there!
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This line is fine vertically, but I can't use my marginpar!
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\mtext` from within the nested item?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the tip! It never crossed my mind to try that. I sort of prefer to have these things attached to the object of interest `itemi`, since I can then more freely move the `itemii` parts without having to keep track of things.

Comment: The thing that introduces the empty line is `\makebox[0pt]{}`

Comment: @siracusa You're right, but that's needed otherwise the marginpar is also not correctly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I can propose two ways of solving the problem: one  I mentioned in a comment (adding the marginal note from within the nested enumerate), and another from within the outer enumerate, using the possibilities of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\newcommand{\mtext}{\leavevmode\marginpar{(hello)}}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{enumerate}%
\item%
\mtext
\begin{enumerate}[before =\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+2\topsep }]
    \item This is a line too low, at least the marginpar is there!
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This line is fine vertically, but I can't use my marginpar! \mtext%
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to get back into vmode in the middle of a line is to use a minipage.  This is certainly not the easiest solution, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mtext}{\leavevmode\marginpar{(hello)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \mtext
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a line too low, at least the marginpar is there!
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```